# How to change my HTML code to ASP code?

Tags: html, asp.net

M new for this site to ask a question. Bt Have been lots of time to find an answer.. I love it.
Now I have created an HTML including js & css files project. But now I have to convert it into asp as I need to connect to backend. So pls help me out if u can..

Advance thanks

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have to do database connectivity at backend.

1. Before doing anything first read basics of asp.net and C#/VB.Net, databases and Web Server.
2. Once you have read that, then try to convert your existing code into asp.net.
3. And while converting if you feel any problem then describe your specific problem and get the solution from Stackoverflow community.

   [Here you can read about basics](http://www.asp.net/web-forms)